# Regular expression in COPY INTO command in Snowflake

Tags: sql, regex, azure, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

I have few CSV files in azure blob storage, and we are using COPY INTO command to load the files in snowflake table.
The problem is:
The file system is: container >> folder (Ex: account) >> Number of files like 2011-09.csv 2011-10.csv likewise and account folder also has a sub-folder 'Snapshot' which also has files that has similar data but with different name like 2019-11_1654478715.csv
So while using COPY INTO command, the target table in Snowflake is populated with duplicate rows.

Iam using this one:

copy into BINGO_DWH_DEV.LANDING.CRM_ACCOUNT_TEMP from 'azure://abc.blob.core.windows.net/abc-abc/account' credentials=(azure_sas_token= 'abc') ON_ERROR='CONTINUE' FILE_FORMAT=(type=csv field_delimiter=',' FIELD_OPTIONALLY_ENCLOSED_BY='"');

Any ideas where I can use COPY INTO command with regular expression that can pick only the files like '2011-09.csv' and not the files from the Snapshot folder.

Appreciate your help

Comment: One way you can achieve is to pass the full file name by a loop on the top of the copy command

Comment: Automating it, instead of manual want to use regex

Answer (score 8):

You can use pattern keyword as regular expressions to insert files based on pattern.

Please refer to [the Snowflake documentation](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/getting-started-tutorial-copy-into.html).

Example:

```
copy into emp_basic
  from @%emp_basic
  file_format = (type = csv field_optionally_enclosed_by='"')
  pattern = '.*2011-19.*.csv.gz'
  on_error = 'continue';
```

It depends on how you set the stage location (Azure blob or S3 or GCP). Let’s say that your files get landed in the "folder" `s3://yourbucket/folder1/[filename],gz`. And that you've set your stage to point to `s3://yourbucket` used pattern:

```
pattern='.*2011-09*.csv.*.gz'
```

Then it will scan all files under `s3://yourbucket`.

If however your stage has been setup to point to the folder `s3://yourbucket/folder1/` and the pattern used is:

```
pattern='.*2011-09.*csv.*.gz'
```

Then it will look only in `s3://yourbucket/folder1/`.

Comment: Thanks for this.  Helped me out. - some extended use cases. If your stage has folders the syntax PATTERN='.*folder1/.*2011-09.*csv.*.gz' is useful.   As is the fact that the LIST command supports PATTERN for testing prior to your COPY INTO.  e.g. LIST @%emp_basic PATTERN='.*2011-09*.csv.*.gz'